# htaccess redirect if ip isn't in white list only in certain path

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

i try to redirect users if they have a specific ip and if the path to which access is "admin", use the following lines but does not work (redirect with any route) :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.123\.123\.123|123\.123\.123\.123)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin$
RewriteRule !^maintenance/ / [R=302,L]
```

I use laravel htaccess full code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front UserController...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.123\.123\.123|123\.123\.123\.123)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !+/admin$
    RewriteRule !^maintenance/ / [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There a specific reason you're not using Apache's access control?  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: @Devon Because I don't have access to ssh or cpanel, only ftp

Comment: mod_authz_host rules are allowed in htaccess